# How do I control evaluation order?

Tags: batch-file

For example, `cd (echo ..)` works in powershell, but how do I get it working in batch (it evaluates the echo first, and so the command is effectively `cd ..`)? `mycommand.exe (ls -fi *.hs -exclude \"#*\" -name -r)` is what I'm actually trying to convert (it sends a, completed, filtered file listing to `mycommand`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set LIST=
for /r %%F in (*.hs) do (
   set "FN=%%F"
   if not "!FN:~0,1!"=="#" set LIST=!LIST! "%%F"
)
mycommand.exe !LIST!
```

would be a rough translation.

Comment: This works, but is there a way to do it without using a .bat file? I.e., just from cmd.exe?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can probably put it in a single line, but that would not be nice to read.

Answer (score 0):

add the `$` symbol to evaluate the commands in the parens first:

```
mycommand.exe $(ls -fi *.hs -exclude \"#*\" -name -r)
```

or

```
ls -fi *.hs -exclude \"#*\" -name -r | mycommand.exe
```

If you want to execute the command for each item returned from your ls, you can:

```
ls -fi *.hs -exclude \"#*\" -name -r | %{mycommand.exe $_ }
```

Comment: No, I want the first behavior; do you know how to do the same from cmd.exe (dos shell) rather than powershell?

Comment: I would install mingw and just use `xargs`. Cheapest way to get light-weight bash goodness on windows. But you could just try `dir | mycommand.exe` in DOS.

Comment: This is nonsense. `cmd` is not a Unix shell and thus does not adhere to the same rules. `dir | mycommand` will also do something entirely different. `cmd` also has nothing to do with DOS at all.